# Selected item not working in Picker

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms

In our edit page, we have an issue to populate the value into Selected Item in picker and it won't select for some reason from the LoadCourses() or LoadRoundCategories() either.

Any ideas?

Here's the code:

**ViewModel**

```
public class EditGolfRoundViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    ApiServices _apiServices = new ApiServices();

    private string _message;
    private ObservableCollection<GolfCourse> _courses;
    private ObservableCollection<GolfRoundCategory> _roundCategories;
    private object_selectedGolfCourse;
    private GolfRoundCategory _selectedGolfRoundCategory;
    private GolfRound _golfRound;

    public EditGolfRoundViewModel()
    {
        _selectedGolfCourse = new GolfCourse();
        _selectedGolfRoundCategory = new GolfRoundCategory();
        LoadCourses();
        LoadRoundCategories();
    }

    public GolfRound GolfRound
    {
        get { return _golfRound; }
        set
        {
            _golfRound = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }


    public string Message
    {
        get { return _message; }

        set
        {
            _message = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<GolfCourse> GolfCourses
    {
        get { return _courses; }
        set
        {
            if (_courses != value)
            {
                _courses = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }

        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<GolfRoundCategory> GolfRoundCategories
    {
        get { return _roundCategories; }
        set
        {
            _roundCategories = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public object SelectedGolfCourse
    {
        get { return _selectedGolfCourse; }
        set
        {
            _selectedGolfCourse = value;
            var golfCourse = _selectedGolfCourse as GolfCourse;
            Guid tempGolfCourseID = golfCourse.GolfCourseID;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedGolfCourse");
        }
    }


    public GolfRoundCategory SelectedGolfRoundCategory
    {
        get { return _selectedGolfRoundCategory; }
        set
        {
            _selectedGolfRoundCategory = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }



    public ICommand EditCommand 
    { 
        get
        {
            return new Command(async() =>
            {
                GolfRound.GolfCourseID = SelectedGolfCourse.GolfCourseID;
                GolfRound.GolfCourse = SelectedGolfCourse;
                GolfRound.GolfRoundCategoryID = SelectedGolfRoundCategory.GolfRoundCategoryID;
                GolfRound.GolfRoundCategory = SelectedGolfRoundCategory;
                GolfRound.LastModifiedUTC = System.DateTime.Now;

                await _apiServices.PutGolfRoundAsync(GolfRound, Settings.AccessToken);
            });
        }

    }

    public ICommand DeleteCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new Command(async () =>
            {
                await _apiServices.DeleteGolfRoundAsync(GolfRound.GolfRoundID, Settings.AccessToken);
            });
        }

    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private async void LoadCourses()
    {
        GolfCourses = new ObservableCollection<GolfCourse>(await _apiServices.GetGolfCoursesAsync(Settings.AccessToken));
    }

    private async void LoadRoundCategories()
    {
        GolfRoundCategories = new ObservableCollection<GolfRoundCategory>(await _apiServices.GetGolfRoundCategoriesAsync(Settings.AccessToken));
    }

}
```

**View - XAML**

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:AthlosifyMobile.ViewModels.Golf"
         x:Class="AthlosifyMobile.Views.EditGolfRoundPage">

<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="Center" Spacing="30" Padding="30">
    <Entry Text="{Binding GolfRound.Name}" Placeholder="name" FontSize="Default" />
    <Entry Text="{Binding GolfRound.Notes}" Placeholder="notes" FontSize="Default" />
    <Entry Text="{Binding GolfRound.DailyHandicap}" Placeholder="daily handicap" FontSize="Default" />
    <Label Text="Date" />
    <DatePicker Date="{Binding GolfRound.TeeOffUTC}" 
                Format="D"
                Margin="30, 0, 0, 30"  />
    <Picker x:Name="pCourse" Title="Course" ItemsSource="{Binding GolfCourses}" 
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedGolfCourse, Mode=TwoWay}" 
            ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Name}"></Picker>
    <Entry Text="{Binding GolfRound.GolfCourse.Name}" Placeholder="selected golf course" FontSize="Default" />
    <Picker x:Name="pCategory" Title="Category" ItemsSource="{Binding GolfRoundCategories}" 
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedGolfRoundCategory, Mode=TwoWay}"
            ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Name}"></Picker>
    <Entry Text="{Binding SelectedGolfRoundCategory.Name}" Placeholder="selected round category" FontSize="Default" />
    <Button Command="{Binding EditCommand}" Text="Edit Round" />
    <Button Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}" Text="Delete Round" />

    <Label Text="{Binding Message}" ></Label>
</StackLayout>
```

**View - code behind**

```
public partial class EditGolfRoundPage : ContentPage
{
    public EditGolfRoundPage (GolfRound round)
    {
        var editGolfRoundViewModel = new EditGolfRoundViewModel();
        editGolfRoundViewModel.GolfRound = round;

        BindingContext = editGolfRoundViewModel;

        InitializeComponent ();

        //var editGolfRoundViewModel = new EditGolfRoundViewModel();
        //editGolfRoundViewModel.GolfRound = round;
        //editGolfRoundViewModel.SelectedGolfCourse = round.GolfCourse;

        //BindingContext = editGolfRoundViewModel;

    }
}
```

Comment: does you not included class GolfRound support INotifyPropertyChanged? Since you're binding to it and setting it from that binding it probably should.

Comment: @Kenny : I did actually and if you look at the ViewModel above. I added OnPropertyChanged() on the setter.

Comment: @dcpartners Did you ever find a resolution for this? Having a similar issue...

Answer (score 20):

Implement [`IEquatable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iequatable-1) for class of property used in `SelectedItem`:

```
public class GolfCourse : IEquatable<GolfCourse>
{
    ...
    public bool Equals(GolfCourse other)
    {
        if (other == null) return false;
        return (this.Name.Equals(other.Name));
    }
}
```

Usage, assuming `ItemsSource` contains an object with value of `Name` as shown below:

```
SelectedGolfCourse = new GolfCourse { Name = "Course 2" };
```

Comment: I assume the GolfCourse class is within the Models?!?!

Comment: We implemented that one and still no default set in the picker :(

Comment: Could be this is a bug within UWP ?

Comment: The above should work with Xamarin.Forms version 3.1.0.583944 on UWP. However, see [github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues)

Comment: Yes now its working, it seems that the picker can't find the object when a custom Equals method is missing and resets itself

Comment: This should be the answer. It solved the problem for me, thanks!

Answer (score 9):

The following is true as of Xamarin Forms v4.7.

See if you are doing this:

```
<Picker x:Name="DefaultEntitlement" Title="Entitlement"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedOwnerEntitlement, Mode=TwoWay}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding OwnerEntitlements, Mode=TwoWay}">
</Picker>
```

Instead of this:

```
<Picker x:Name="DefaultEntitlement" Title="Entitlement"
    ItemsSource="{Binding OwnerEntitlements, Mode=TwoWay}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedOwnerEntitlement, Mode=TwoWay}">
</Picker>
```

Comment: Aargh. This was my problem. Thanks!

Comment: This was my issue, too. I didn't know the order of the properties would matter...

Comment: Wow! I didn't know that the order is important.

Comment: The order didn't matter in my case.  SelectedItem is after ItemSource and it still works OK.  In my case it wasn't working because I was not calling the OnPropertyChanged() method in the setter for the bound variable.

Comment: ORDER is ALSO important to MAUI .NET 7...

Comment: @BryanCass same here, even with XF v.5.0.0.2622.  I utilized Label's IsVisible binding with a property of the SelectedItem. However, it did not update.
Doesn't seem right that it is necessary to explicitly call OnPropertyChanged method for the selecteditem binding.

Answer (score 0):

Xaml

```
    <Picker x:Name="ProductPicker" WidthRequest="220"    HeightRequest="35" Title="Select" ItemsSource="{Binding ProductList}" SelectedItem="{Binding ProductSelected}" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding ProductName}">   </Picker>
```

ViewModel

```
 public List<ProductModel> ProductList { get; set; }
```

Populating Data in Datasource in Viewmodel

```
    ProductList = Products.Result.ToList();
```

Getting Selected Data

```
   private object _ProductSelected;
      public object ProductSelected
    {
        get { return _ProductSelected; }
        set
        {
            _ProductSelected = value;
             ProductSelected_SelectedIndex.Execute(value);
             OnPropertyChanged("ProductSelected"); //in case you are using MVVM Light
        }
    }

 private Command ProductSelected_SelectedIndex
    {
        get
        {
            return new Command((e) =>
            {


          }}}



 private object _CitySelectedFromList;
    public object CitySelectedFromList
    {
        get { return _CitySelectedFromList; }
        set
        {
            _CitySelectedFromList = value;
            var cityid = _CitySelectedFromList as CityMasterModel;
            tempcityids = Convert.ToInt32(cityid.Id);

        }
    }
```

Comment: @dcpartners your business logic

Comment: Actually I can get the Selected Data no-problem ... the main issue is that after populate the list I want to have the default of the picker is the one that it's on the database/webservice originally. For instance if I have a list of animal object "cat", "dog", "monkey" and in my database (Webservice) has a value of "dog" ... so I want to default pick is "dog" not blank list

Comment: Are you updating to "public object CitySelectedFromList" ? Not sure how this will accomplish setting up the default selection of the picker ? Still confused from my end.

Comment: @dcpartners i can't make simple than this, this is the direct answer for what you looking for, but still i could help more if you try to implement the above code and share the updated code

Comment: I've changed accordingly (looked the code above) and still the same. I don't see the point to ProductSelected_SelectedIndex.Execute(value); will make a different though

Comment: i am talking about this code `  var cityid = _CitySelectedFromList as CityMasterModel;
            tempcityids = Convert.ToInt32(cityid.Id);
`

Comment: With this code, are you trying to make a trigger change on ID field ? Is that what you trying to do?

Comment: Did change it and still the same (see public object SelectedGolfCourse in the ViewModel

Answer (score 0):

you are binding view model before  Initialise page so that is wrong thing we can not bind data without Initialise page fro that you need to change code of xaml.cs like below

    `public EditGolfRoundPage (GolfRound round)
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        BindingContext = editGolfRoundViewModel;
        BindingContext.GolfRound = round;
    }`

that will work for you 
Happy Coding :)

Comment: Tried the approach above and it's the same thing. I can populate fields in any control ie. Text, Date Picker BUT not the normal picker ?!?!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try once replacing your Viewmodel. I have changed the type from Object to actual type. Set the Default item while loading the items from endpoint.

```
public class EditGolfRoundViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
ApiServices _apiServices = new ApiServices();

private string _message;
private ObservableCollection<GolfCourse> _courses;
private ObservableCollection<GolfRoundCategory> _roundCategories;
private GolfCourse _selectedGolfCourse;
private GolfRoundCategory _selectedGolfRoundCategory;
private GolfRound _golfRound;

public EditGolfRoundViewModel()
{
    LoadCourses();
    LoadRoundCategories();
}

public GolfRound GolfRound
{
    get { return _golfRound; }
    set
    {
        _golfRound = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}


public string Message
{
    get { return _message; }

    set
    {
        _message = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}

public ObservableCollection<GolfCourse> GolfCourses
{
    get { return _courses; }
    set
    {
        if (_courses != value)
        {
            _courses = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }

    }
}

public ObservableCollection<GolfRoundCategory> GolfRoundCategories
{
    get { return _roundCategories; }
    set
    {
        _roundCategories = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}

public GolfCourse SelectedGolfCourse
{
    get { return _selectedGolfCourse; }
    set
    {
        _selectedGolfCourse = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("SelectedGolfCourse");
    }
}


public GolfRoundCategory SelectedGolfRoundCategory
{
    get { return _selectedGolfRoundCategory; }
    set
    {
        _selectedGolfRoundCategory = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}



public ICommand EditCommand
{
    get
    {
        return new Command(async () =>
        {
            GolfRound.GolfCourseID = SelectedGolfCourse.GolfCourseID;
            GolfRound.GolfCourse = SelectedGolfCourse;
            GolfRound.GolfRoundCategoryID = SelectedGolfRoundCategory.GolfRoundCategoryID;
            GolfRound.GolfRoundCategory = SelectedGolfRoundCategory;
            GolfRound.LastModifiedUTC = System.DateTime.Now;

            await _apiServices.PutGolfRoundAsync(GolfRound, Settings.AccessToken);
        });
    }

}

public ICommand DeleteCommand
{
    get
    {
        return new Command(async () =>
        {
            await _apiServices.DeleteGolfRoundAsync(GolfRound.GolfRoundID, Settings.AccessToken);
        });
    }

}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

[NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}

private async void LoadCourses()
{
    GolfCourses = new ObservableCollection<GolfCourse>(await _apiServices.GetGolfCoursesAsync(Settings.AccessToken));
    if (GolfCourses != null && GolfCourses.Count() > 0)
        SelectedGolfCourse = GolfCourses[0];
}

private async void LoadRoundCategories()
{
    GolfRoundCategories = new ObservableCollection<GolfRoundCategory>(await _apiServices.GetGolfRoundCategoriesAsync(Settings.AccessToken));
    if (GolfRoundCategories != null && GolfRoundCategories.Count() > 0)
        SelectedGolfRoundCategory = GolfRoundCategories[0];

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

- make sure your prop support `INotifyPropertyChanged`
- make sure `Selected Item` variable has initial value
- try debug your `selected item` variable, make sure has value

**1. Initials**

Take a look your code:

```
public EditGolfRoundViewModel()
{
    _selectedGolfCourse = new GolfCourse();
    _selectedGolfRoundCategory = new GolfRoundCategory();
    LoadCourses();
    LoadRoundCategories();
}
```

If you try to initial value `Selected Item`, don't do this:

```
_selectedGolfCourse = new GolfCourse();
_selectedGolfRoundCategory = new GolfRoundCategory();
```

let it `null`, is fine. You can do like this:

```
SelectedGolfRoundCategory = new GolfRoundCategory();
//or
SelectedGolfRoundCategory = dataFromAPI;
```

**2. Assign**

Take a look your code:

```
public ICommand EditCommand 
{ 
    get
    {
        return new Command(async() =>
        {
            GolfRound.GolfCourseID = SelectedGolfCourse.GolfCourseID;
            GolfRound.GolfCourse = SelectedGolfCourse;
            GolfRound.GolfRoundCategoryID = SelectedGolfRoundCategory.GolfRoundCategoryID;
            GolfRound.GolfRoundCategory = SelectedGolfRoundCategory;
            GolfRound.LastModifiedUTC = System.DateTime.Now;

            await _apiServices.PutGolfRoundAsync(GolfRound, Settings.AccessToken);
        });
    }
 }
```

You trying `selected item` variable insert into to object `GolfRound`, like this part:

```
  GolfRound.GolfRoundCategoryID = SelectedGolfRoundCategory.GolfRoundCategoryID;
  GolfRound.GolfRoundCategory = SelectedGolfRoundCategory;
```

Make sure you have `INotifyPropertyChanged` implement this model `GolfRound` for prop `GolfRoundCategoryID` and `GolfRoundCategory`. If not, it would not work. I have experience for this.

Hope this helpful.